# Compound linear regression model with unique slopes and offsets for subsets of data in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am hoping somebody may be able to help me with some guidance in using scikit-learn.
I am working with a system that currently uses linear regression to generate predictions based on a set of about 20 features. The current model is as follows.

y<sub>i</sub>=P<sub>0</sub>+P<sub>1</sub>x<sub>i1</sub>+...+P<sub>k</sub>x<sub>ik</sub>

Where

x<sub>ik</sub> are the k features for observation i.

P<sub>k</sub> are the k parameters of the model.

y<sub>i</sub> is the predicted result for observation i.

So far this is very easy to work with and performs quite well for the data collected. In practice the data is collected at different installations. We have found that whilst we can find values of P<sub>k</sub> that work very well at one installation we typically have to apply a slope and offset to the model above to fit the data from another installation. The model then becomes.

y<sub>i</sub>=S<sub>0</sub>+S<sub>1</sub>(P<sub>0</sub>+P<sub>1</sub>x<sub>i1</sub>+...+P<sub>k</sub>x<sub>ik</sub>)

Where
S<sub>0</sub> and S<sub>1</sub> are the parameters of the model that are unique to a given installation.

We have tried simply adding all the data together to find a global set of P<sub>k</sub> values that do not require installation adjustment but this tends to produce worse performing models. My thought was to build a model as follows.

y<sub>i</sub>=S<sub>0n</sub>+S<sub>1n</sub>(P<sub>0</sub>+P<sub>1</sub>x<sub>i1</sub>+...+P<sub>k</sub>x<sub>ik</sub>)

Where
S<sub>0n</sub> and S<sub>1n</sub> are the parameters of the model that are unique for each of the n installations.

Each observation would be tagged with which of the n sites it was associated with. The full set of parameters for the model would now be P<sub>k</sub>, S<sub>0n</sub> and S<sub>1n</sub>.

I have been investigating scikit-learn as I would also like to test other Machine Learning algorithms in a consistent manner on the data set. But I am not sure how I would go about implementing the above model using scikit-learn or if there is a specifc name for this type of model.

I have been looking at section 6.1 of the User Guide relating to Pipelines and Composite Estimators but I don’t think they are the correct tool from my understanding.

Do you think I may have to roll my own estimator or use something like scipy.optimze to find these parameters?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just some ideas: You could encode the plant number into a one-hot encoding which will produce 20 extra features but allows you to use one linear model. - You might be able to reduce the number of features using dimension reduction techniques such as svd and pca. - The model you describe is no longer linear but quadratic.

Comment: @joostblack, thanks so much for that. I think I can see a way forward now.